# How to "readfile" in Beanstalk PHP

Tags: php, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, file-get-contents, readfile

I have my project zipped and uploaded to AWS Beanstalk. I then have to manually configure for the `Document root` which is: /api-test-beanstalk

My index file is located within this directory, so:

```
zip --> api-test-beanstalk --> index.php
```

Inside index.php Im trying to read in a file located inside the same folder called abc.php, so I tried:

```
$file = '/api-test-beanstalk/abc.php';
echo file_get_contents($file);

$file = 'api-test-beanstalk/abc.php';
echo file_get_contents($file);

$file = '/abc.php';
echo file_get_contents($file);

$file = 'abc.php';
echo file_get_contents($file);
```

Nothing seems to work, all result in error that looks like this:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(api-test-beanstalk/abc.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/app/current/api-test-beanstalk/index.php on line 67
```

How do I read in abc.php inside index.php? The files are next to each other in the same folder.

Comment: did you commit abc.php alongside index.php?

Comment: @Tal Yes, they are in the same folder called api-test-beanstalk which is in a ZIP folder

Comment: Nevermind, found the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify ABSOLUTE Path

```
$file = './abs.php'; 
readfile($file);
```

Reg path: Refer this [LINK](http://www.coffeecup.com/help/articles/absolute-vs-relative-pathslinks/)

Comment: I would rather not do a http request since the file is right next to it, it seems like overkill. Do you perhaps know some workaround ?

Comment: Found the answer: `$file = './abs.php';

readfile($file);` Thanks will accept

Comment: if your **index.php** & **abc.php** in same folder definitely it will work. I have tested in my  local

Comment: It did not work on Beanstalk, nevermind I found the answer, code above. Thanks for your time